# Decoding RLE in CUDA efficiently

Tags: cuda, compression, run-length-encoding

I need to decode an RLE in CUDA and I have been trying to think about the most efficient way of expanding the RLE into a list with all my values. So Say my values are 2, 3, 4 and my runs are 3, 3 , 1 I want to expand that to  2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4.

At first I thought I could use `cudaMemset` but I am pretty sure now that launches a Kernel and I have CUDA Compute Capability 3.0 so even if it were not probably inefficient to launch a new kernel for each value / run pair I do not have dynamic parallelism available to do this.

So I want to know if this solution is sound before I go and implement it since there are so many things that end up not working well on CUDA if you aren't being clever. Would it be reasonable to make a kernel that will call `cudaMalloc` then cudaMemCpy to the destination? I can easily compute the prefix sums to know where to copy the memory to and from and make all my reading at least coalesced. What I am worried about is calling `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemCpy` so many times.

Another potential option is writing these values to shared memory and then copying those to global memory. I want to know if my first solution should work and be efficient or if I have to do the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to think about doing a separate operation (e.g. `cudaMalloc`, or `cudaMemset`) for each value/run pair.

After computing the prefix sum on the run sequence, the last value in the prefix sum will be the total allocation size.  Use that for a single `cudaMalloc` operation for the entire final expanded sequence.

Once you have the necessary space allocated, and the prefix sum computed, the actual expansion is pretty straightforward.

[thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) can make this pretty easy if you want a fast prototype.  There is [an example code](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/expand.cu) for it.

Comment: Robert you are one of the most awesome people around. You have solved every problem I have ever run into on CUDA. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@RobertCrovella is of course correct, but you can go even further in terms of efficiency if you have the leeway to slightly tweak your compression sceheme.

Sorry for the self-plugging, but you might be interested in [my own implementation](https://bitbucket.org/eyalroz/db-kernel-testbench/issues/) of a variant of Run-Length Encoding, with the addition of anchoring of output positions into the input (e.g.. "in which offset in which run do we have the 2048th element?"); this allows for a more equitable assignment of work to thread blocks and avoids the need for a full-blown prefix sum. It's still a work-in-progress, so I only get ~34 GB/sec on a 336 GB/sec memory bandwidth card (Titan X) at the time of writing, but it's quite usable.